# Add/Edit Entities in google app engine java local datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Following are related to GAE/J local development setup:

1. How do i add/edit entities in local datastore (preferably using some UI)? `_ah/admin` allows only to view entities.
2. In the local JUnit test cases, how to access the same datastore data that my local web application writes to? I wrote my Test Cases in accordance with http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html but the test cases don't access the same data that the web application uses.
3. How to save local datastore data between clean-build (right now local_db.bin is written in the target directory which gets cleaned every now and then)

Stack being used :

- Google AppEngine for Java - (gae sdk
  1.4/ java sdk 6),
- Netbeans-6.9.1,
- Maven-2 (maven-gae-plugin 0.7.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't currently edit entities in the Java local datastore viewer. It's in the todo list, though.
2. Your unit tests shouldn't rely on the contents of the datastore: unit tests are intended to be self-contained.
3. You can't do this, either, unless you make a backup of `local_db.bin` part of your build process. Again, you should ideally design your app with easy reloading of data in mind.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I agree for #2 that tests cases should be self-contained and should not change the application state. But for #3, one may need to clean build the project without losing the data. I mean, Application data and source code have different lifecycles..

Comment: I disagree with #2. I struggle with the same issue and I don't see the value in that comment.  The whole purpose of local_db.bin is to provide local test environment before deploying an application.

Comment: @Daghan Yes - for informal testing by users. Your unit tests, in order to be self-contained, shouldn't rely on the contents of it.

Comment: Nick, I have to eat up my initial comment. After 10 or so hours, I managed to open the same database only to corrupt it with my unit test, so indeed you were right. Initially I was too lazy to modify the unit test to create the same database state but after the whole ordeal I regret the "shortcut" which ended up taking 3 times more work

Comment: For 1#, Editing Entity Locally, You could use AppWrench, http://appwrench.onpositive.com/viewer.page

Comment: @NickJohnson what is the timeline for #1.  Is this functionality still on the todo six years later?  If so, what's the ETA?

Answer (score 2):

Now you can save/load entities [using a command line client](https://github.com/inpun/gaecl)